# Last command on .sh files won't run

Tags: 12.10, startup

I have this script in a *.sh file to enable natural scrolling. I've added it to `Startup Application`.

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput set-prop 11 268 -106 -106
nautilus -q && nautilus -n
```

The problem is, whenever I login, the last command (`nautilus -n`) won't run -which is annoying because I can't use the Super button to open Dash- and I have to run nautilus manually. What's wrong?

UPDATE:

I have tested my script above on terminal line-by-line, and it works fine. The problems only appear when I run it from .sh file.

`nautilus -q && touch $HOME/Desktop/reported-success.txt` give me the txt file,

and the result of `nautilus -q && nautilus -n &> $HOME/nautilus-output.log` is :

```
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.4.0
```

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but just for the record: You did end the script with a linefeed/enter character or an empty line did you ? (If not, then the last command won't be executed.)

Comment: No I didn't. Just an additional line or empty space didn't work either. But you're right, I changed the last line to nautilus -q && nautilus -n &&[enter], and it works, thanks alot. How do I make your comment as an answer @thom ?

Comment: @Nur: s/he'll have to do that her/himself. It's a very subtle thing indeed and a good point. It's something that wouldn't be visible here with the code formatting.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Then, what should I do with this question?

Comment: @Nur: simply wait for thom to write an answer. I can also edit it into my answer if you prefer that. The possibility had crossed my mind initially, but I had discounted it (wrongly, it seems).

Comment: sorry to be late, i've had a very busy month, I added my comment as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End the script with a linefeed/enter character or an empty line
or else the last command won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Well from the script that means that `nautilus -q` returned a non-zero exit code. Hence the `&&` evaluates to false and `nautilus -n` doesn't get executed.

You tell it: run `nautilus -n` **if** `nautilus -q` succeeded. The definition of success is an exit code of `0` in the shell.

Use `;` instead of `&&` to do it unconditionally or use a small wrapper script to translate the possible return codes that you want to accept as "success" into `0`.

Another method to tear down running `nautilus` instances is obviously to use `pkill` this way:

```
pkill -u $(whoami) ^nautilus
```

You may want to specify a particular signal (`pkill -SIGNALNAME -u ...`), but I found no documentation on which signals `nautilus` reacts to.

The above command kills all instances of `nautilus` running as you (the `whoami`).

---

Use this to figure out what the first command (`nautilus -q`) returned:

```
nautilus -q || echo "exit code: $?"
```

What do you see? If it's not `0` then this is clearly the problem just the way the script logic suggests.

Comment: Addressing just the first part of this answer (the part that is an answer, whereas the second part is purely a request for information): This is probably not a very good solution, because the goal is to successfully *restart* Nautilus so that the changes made by the `xinput` command are applied.

Comment: @EliahKagan: I see. I use Ubuntu as terminal-only, so I had to look up `nautilus -q` anyway. Let me address this.

Comment: @0xC0000022L no output from nautilus -q || echo "exit code: $?", it just quit nautilus as usual, and I have to run nautilus manually again. And changing && with ; didn't work either.

Comment: @Nur: what about (the last line) as `(nautilus -q || pkill -u $(whoami) ^nautilus || true) && (sleep 2; nautilus -n)`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L The same. Works in terminal. Works in separate (another) .sh file. But didn't work on my script.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` give? Use that same shell in the shebang of your script and see whether that works.